# Avoiding repeated names in JSON with MongoEngine - Python

Tags: python, json, flask, mongoengine

I'm looking for a way/function/method to make it impossible to save two identical names on my JSON, for example, I got this JSON with repeated names:

```
[
  [
    {
      "id": "59a5c80dc75969297837c51e",
      "name": "uza",
      "password": "3648726"
    },
    {}
  ],
  [
    {
      "id": "59a5c811c75969297837c51f",
      "name": "kuza",
      "password": "3648726"
    },
    {}
  ],
  [
    {
      "id": "59a5c83ec75969297837c520",
      "name": "kuza",
      "password": "3648726"
    },
    {}
  ]
]
```

My code that creates an user is this one:

```
@api.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def create():

# Grabs the data from the requisition
user_json = request.get_json(silent=True)
if not user_json:
    return "FAIL"

# creates an entity JSON
user, errors = schema.load(user_json)
if bool(errors):
    return jsonify(errors)
    user.save()
return "SUCCESS"
```

Again, I'm using mongoengine, anybody knows how to do it?

Edited to add my model.py

```
rom mongoengine import Document
from mongoengine import StringField, ReferenceField

import marshmallow_mongoengine as ma

from marshmallow import Schema, fields

from .service import ImageService

class User(Document):
    name = StringField(unique=True)
    password = StringField(unique=True)

class Face(Document):
    user = ReferenceField(User)
    image = StringField()
    embedding = StringField()

    def get_embedding(self):
        return ImageService().from_base64_flat(self.embedding.encode())

    def get_image(self):
        return ImageService().from_base64(self.image.encode())

class UserSchema(ma.ModelSchema):
    class Meta:
        model = User

class FaceSchema(ma.ModelSchema):
    class Meta:
        model = Face

    image = ma.fields.Method(deserialize="img_to_base64", serialize="img_to_base64")
    embedding = ma.fields.Method(deserialize="to_base64", serialize="to_base64")

    def img_to_base64(self, data):
        return ImageService().to_base64(data)

    def to_base64(self, data):
        return ImageService().np_to_base64(data)
```

In the class User i changed it from required to unique, now i can't add one with the same name but in exchange it returns an INTERNAL SERVER ERROR on Insomnia, and as you can see i put another unique on the password for test and it didn't worked it saves even if there is another user with the same password.

Comment: You current error or issue?

Comment: the name is repeated. i need it to not save repeated names.

Comment: Can you post the schema also that you have used?

Comment: it is the one from marshmallow API, but i think i got it, and i think my Visual Code was bugging, problem is that i can only put one unique. i'll put the model.py from my code.

Comment: i edited the post with more pieces of the code and explanations of what's happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
class User(Document):
    name = StringField(unique=True)
    password = StringField(unique=True)
    meta = {       
        'indexes': [{'fields': ['name'], 'unique': True}]
   }
```

Comment: thanks, but i think it was my ide bugging, now everything is working oO